# Is bad posture bad for anything other than your back?

Tags: medical-science

As a musician, I've had a fair amount of tuition on posture. One in particular, who was teaching [Alexander Technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_technique) said that bad posture could cause seemingly unrelated complaints, as slouching causes extra pressure on the internal organs, interferes with breathing etc.

I can find evidence that good posture helps with back pain, but not for any other problems. Is there any evidence that bad posture can cause other problems?

Comment: Good point, although I'm referring to the effects of bad posture, not with any related activity.

Comment: Bad typing posture can lead to neck and wrist problems I believe

Just looking at your monitor wrong can cause neck pain..

Comment: Well, if you are hanged by your hands you risk death by suffocation - does that count as bad posture? ;-)

Comment: If this were pedants.stackexchange.com you might have a point...

Comment: @Akash,  Posture is overrated. I spent the better part of 40 years behind a desk in a very bad-posture position: slouched down so that my shoulders were at the height of the missing arm-rests, with the leading edge of the seat providing lumbar support. Occasionally an ergonomic expert would visit our department to make sure everyone had the latest trend in chairs etc. They gave me up as a lost cause, and I stuck with my utilitarian 1960s IBM keypunch chairs (I had a few spares stashed away for when they eventually broke).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Posture seems to be connected to the [likelihood of injury in sports](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8832472/). (**Journal of Orthopedic Sports Physical Therapy**

Posture can also affect whether food/drink is [swallowed or aspirated](http://www.springerlink.com/content/c03km3bkthlctf6p/). (**American Journal of Roentgenology**)

Posture is [related to fatigue](http://www.springerlink.com/content/c03km3bkthlctf6p/) for a person who is standing for a long period of time. (**Surgical Endoscopy**) (Incidentally, I can back this up with personal experience -- I teach, and the better my posture, the less tired and achy I am after a day of teaching. However, I figured I'd give the research first, since one person's experience isn't enough data for scientific evaluation.)

Posture can tell you a lot about the [attitude, status, and interest](https://doi.org/10.1037/h0027349) of the person you're talking with. (**Psychological Bulletin**)

Good posture can also affect [motivation, stress, and mood](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00992249). (**Motivation and Emotion**)

Comment: The links to `springerlink.com` are broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshots saved on the Wayback Machine.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist possibly http://doi.org/10.2214/ajr.160.5.8470567 for AJR, and pick one from https://link.springer.com/search?query=posture+fatigue+standing&search-within=Journal&facet-journal-id=464 for SE